# How to prevent VSCode from reordering python imports across statements?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

This is the [correct way](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to import Gtk3 into python:

```py
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GObject
```

When I save such code in VSCode with `"editor.formatOnSave": true`, it gets reordered to:

```py
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
```

which makes Gtk to be loaded before I have the chance to specify the version I am using, which at very least leads to the following warning being displayed:

```
PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '4.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
```

or worse, get me an exception like:

```
ValueError: Namespace Gtk is already loaded with version 4.0
```

Now, I like VSCode code formatting, but I don't want it to reorder my imports, specially not across statements (being that imports in python have side effects). How to properly use VSCode's Python code formatter with Gtk?

Comment: Im not sure what engine it is using to sort the imports, if it is isort you can try this: https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/action_comments.html

Comment: Using the isort comments didn't work. I saw had isort extension installed, removed it, and it still reorders my imports. I don't know who is doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent VSCode from reordering Python imports across statements, you can configure the editor to use a specific Python code formatter that maintains the order of the imports as they are in the original code. Here's how you can do it:

- Install the Python extension for VSCode if you haven't already done so.
- Install a Python code formatter that maintains the order of imports, such as `isort` or `yapf`. You can do this by running the command pip install isort or pip install yapf in your terminal.
- In VSCode, open the settings by clicking on the gear icon in the bottom left corner and selecting "Settings".
- Search for "Python › Formatting: Provider" in the search bar.
- Select "Edit in settings.json" to edit the settings.json file.
- Add the following line to the file, depending on which code formatter you installed:
- For isort: "python.formatting.provider": "isort"
- For yapf: "python.formatting.provider": "yapf"
- Save the file and close the settings.

Comment: Thanks! It was using `autopep8`. I changed it to `black` and it doesn't reorder these imports.

Comment: Happy to help, keep coding.

Answer (score 2):

I did this in my code after the other imports and it seems to work so I can save the code with formatting.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')

if True:
    from gi.repository import GLib
    from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
```